# Meaning of "holds for" in quote

Tags: word-usage

> Bell's inequality **holds for** all non-product states

To my understanding, this sentence should mean "Bell's inequality is correct for all non-product states".
But the true meaning is "Bell's inequality is NOT correct for all non-product states" as indicated in [the original paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/037596019190805I?via%3Dihub).

So what's wrong here?

Comment: Yeah, that title is wrong.  Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hold-for) -

## Hold for

> : to apply or be relevant to

Therefore,

> *Bell's inequality **applies to** or **is relevant to** all non-product states.*

---

So, as Jim mentions in the comment above, your understanding is correct (the title is wrong).

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

## "remains true for"

The phrase "**holds for**" can be replaced with "**remains true for**".

from [**holds true**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hold+true):

> To be or remain true, valid, or applicable.